# C++ Reading Multiple Text File (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have a code like below. In short, it encrypts all the letters in a text file by shifting 3 rows (Caesar Cipher)
I figured out how to encrypt a single file, but I couldn't figure out how to encrypt multiple files. I don't know much c++ but I need to do this for my project. I was able to come this far by researching. Can someone tell me how I can read multiple files and integrate encryption into this code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

class Sezar
{
public:
    void yaziOku(char *dosyaOku);
    void sifrele(char *dosyaOku, char *dosyaYaz, int key);
    void sifreCoz(char *dosyaOku, char *dosyaYaz, int key);
};

void Sezar::yaziOku(char *dosyaOku)
{
    ifstream input;
    char gecici;
    input.open(dosyaOku);
    cout << "\n\n <--- " << dosyaOku << " ---> işlendi. \n";
    gecici = input.get();
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        gecici = input.get();
    }
    input.close();
}

void Sezar::sifrele(char *dosyaOku, char *dosyaYaz, int key)
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    char gecici;
    input.open(dosyaOku);
    output.open(dosyaYaz);
    gecici = input.get();
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        if (gecici >= 'A' && gecici <= 'Z')
        {
            gecici = (gecici + key);
            if (gecici > 'Z')
            {
                gecici = ((gecici % 'Z') + 'A') - 1;
            }
        }

        if (gecici >= 'a' && gecici <= 'z')
        {
            gecici = (gecici + key);
            if (gecici > 'z')
            {
                gecici = ((gecici % 'z') + 'a') - 1;
            }
        }
        output.put(gecici);
        gecici = input.get();
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
    yaziOku(dosyaOku);
    yaziOku(dosyaYaz);
}

void Sezar::sifreCoz(char *dosyaOku, char *dosyaYaz, int key)
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    char gecici;
    input.open(dosyaOku);
    output.open(dosyaYaz);
    gecici = input.get();
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        if (gecici >= 'A' && gecici <= 'Z')
        {
            gecici = (gecici - key);
            if (gecici > 'Z')
            {
                gecici = ((gecici % 'Z') + 'A') - 1;
            }
        }

        if (gecici >= 'a' && gecici <= 'z')
        {
            gecici = (gecici - key);
            if (gecici < 'a')
            {
                gecici = gecici + 26;
            }
        }

        output.put(gecici);
        gecici = input.get();
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
    yaziOku(dosyaOku);
    yaziOku(dosyaYaz);
}

int main()
{

    Sezar program;
    int secim, key = 3;
    char dosyaOku[30], dosyaYaz[30];
    system("clear");

    cout << "\n Enter the file/Encrypted file to be encrypted: ";
    cin >> dosyaOku;

    cout << "\n Enter the name of the output file: ";
    cin >> dosyaYaz;

    cout << "\n\n 1. Encrypt File\n 2. Decrypt File \n\n Choose one(1 or  2): ";
    cin >> secim;
    if (secim == 1)
        program.sifrele(dosyaOku, dosyaYaz, key);

    else if (secim == 2)
        program.sifreCoz(dosyaOku, dosyaYaz, key);

    else
        cout << "\n\n Wrong choice.";

    getchar();
}
```

I tried to add this code but I couldnt figure out

```
    std::string path = "../Texts";

        for(const auto &entry:filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
        {
            std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        }
```

Compilation error:

```
       error: error: ‘filesystem’ has not been declared
  137 |     for(const auto &entry:filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you commented out? It seems like a good start to finding all files in a directory.

Comment: It gives an error: "‘filesystem’ has not been declared gcc"

Even if I can run it, I don't understand exactly where to write it.

Comment: `std::filesystem` is part of C++17. What compiler version are you using, and are you compiling with `-std=c++17`?

Comment: I am writing the code with visual studio code . But I am running the code in ubuntu terminal(I tried vs code too). I use "gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)" and latest version C/C++ extension in VSCode

Comment: That definitely supports C++17. So: are you compiling the code as C++17?

Comment: yes Where exactly should I write the code? Maybe it's giving an error because of where I wrote it.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the position of the code. Please edit your question with the full compile error.

Comment: To expand on Botje's suggestion, each toolchain (in your case g++) has a default standard, which it will use if you don't tell it which standard you want to use. This is a flag you need to set in your makefile and needs to be passed to your compiler. You can look it up at https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html. For C++17, you need the flag `-std=c++17` (or g++11, where it is the standard).

Comment: TL;DR add `-std=c++17` flag to the compilation command.

Answer (score 0):

A rather old-school way to realize directory traversion looks like this:

```
#include <dirent.h>

if (struct *d = dir("../Texts"))
{   
    while (struct dirent *e = readdir(d))
    {
        if (*e->d_name == '.')
            continue;
        //Do your stuff.
    }
    closedir(d);
}
```

Please refer to https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir for details on how to use it. You may also want to look at `stat`, to discern whether the file you are looking at is a directory, a symlink or a file.

Please note, that `d_name` only contains the filename relative to the directory you opened with `opendir`, meaning, in order to get the actual file path, you will need to join it with the path.